# Using Python to add incrementing integers to files with the same name in a directory

Tags: python

I have thousands of files in a directory all named "Elev_Contour" and I need to figure out how to write a Python script that will add incrementing integers to these files (ex: Elev_Contour1, Elev_Contour2, Elev_Contour3, etc) for all of the files. These files are within subdirectories within the main directory (path: C:\DEM Files\State_Folder\State_location.gdb\featuredataset\Elev_Contour). I need unique names for each file so that I can add them into the table of contents in an ArcMap document (using an Arcpy script that I have already written).

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: How do you have many files with the same name in one directory?

Comment: I think they are in the same directory *tree* "These files are within subdirectories within the main directory "

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do most of this using the os library

I would take a look at

```
import os
```

and in particular

```
os.path
```

and its associations

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need to use the `os.walk()` method to walk the directory tree.

E.g.

```
import os

num = 0

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\DEM Files\\State_Folder\\State_location.gdb\\featuredataset\\Elev_Contour"):
  for filename in files:
    num = num + 1
    old_name = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(root, filename))
    print old_name
    new_name = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(root, "Elev_Contour" + str(num)))
    print new_name
    os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

(Note the double backslashes to escape the backslashes - yay windows)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply traverse directory tree and rename matching files one by one

```
import os

counter = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    if "Elev_Contour" in files:
        fname = os.path.join(root, "Elev_Contour")
        os.rename(fname, "{}{}".format(fname, counter))
        counter += 1
```

Comment: If you're always adding a counter, then you might as well just rename the files numerically... I suspect the OP is after something similar as to https://gist.github.com/joncle/feb07c3dca409ed417ed (but I'm just guessing) - feel free to adapt that into your answer if you wish